# Is it possible to scrape a website's sitemap with no auth

Tags: api

I was wondering if it's possible to access a website's sitemap to scrape their products if you do not have access to their Magento credentials.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the file is publicly accessible (it usually would be), you can view/scrape it.

Try visiting the websites robots.txt file (for example www.google.com/robots.txt) to see where the sitemap is.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for the reply. Would you say that [this](https://www.nakedcph.com/sitemap.xml) website's sitemap is not publicly accessible then? I don't see any products or links to a proper sitemap

Comment: Afraid so, it looks like it's been switched off to me.